# Filtering through array with values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array in which I would like to iterate and filter out based on keys from another array.I need to iterate through the first array and remove that item if the code matches from the second array.I know I should be using array filter but I am not able to get on how to pass the second array as a filter.

```js
var arr =[
  [
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 19,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 40,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 22,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 20,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 40,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 24,
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Total Educated",
      "code": "Q035001",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "9891",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Grade  Less than 9",
      "code": "Q035003",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "514",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Grade 9 to 12",
      "code": "Q035007",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "444",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "High School",
      "code": "Q035011",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "1269",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Some College",
      "code": "Q035012",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "2001",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Associate's",
      "code": "Q035014",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "400",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Bachelor's",
      "code": "Q035015",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "3018",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Master's",
      "code": "Q035016",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "1706",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College - Professional",
      "code": "Q035017",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "315",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree - Doctorate",
      "code": "Q035018",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "224",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Enrollments (Total Population)",
      "code": "EDU_Enrollments",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Nursery school/Preschool",
          "code": "Q036003",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "330",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Kindergarten/Elementary school",
          "code": "Q036006",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "1158",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "High School",
          "code": "Q036015",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "636",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "College/Graduate /Professional school",
          "code": "Q036018",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "1715",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Not Enrolled",
          "code": "Q036024",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "10324",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Percents",
      "code": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "% Grade  Less than 9",
          "code": "XQ035003",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "5.197",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% Grade 9 to 12",
          "code": "XQ035007",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "4.4937",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% High school",
          "code": "XQ035011",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "12.8274",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% Some college",
          "code": "XQ035012",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "20.2347",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Associate",
          "code": "XQ035014",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "4.0479",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Bachelors",
          "code": "XQ035015",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "30.509",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Masters",
          "code": "XQ035016",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "17.2467",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Professional",
          "code": "XQ035017",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "3.1824",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Doctorate",
          "code": "XQ035018",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "2.2612",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "1 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014010",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2395",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "2 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014011",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2140",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "3 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014012",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "878",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "4 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014013",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "701",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "5 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014014",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "247",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "6 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014015",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "68",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "7+ Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014016",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "54",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Persons Per HH",
      "code": "Q017001",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2",
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Occ Managerial Executive",
      "code": "Q050004",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "1748",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Prof Specialty",
      "code": "Q050010",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "2372",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Healthcare Support",
      "code": "Q050024",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "91",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Sales",
      "code": "Q050032",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "1323",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Office Admin",
      "code": "Q050033",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "623",
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Occ Protective",
      "code": "Q050025",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 75,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Food Preparation Serving",
      "code": "Q050028",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 394,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Bldg Maintenance & Cleaning",
      "code": "Q050029",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 183,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Personal Care",
      "code": "Q050030",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 421,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Farming, Fishing & Forestry",
      "code": "Q050034",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Construction",
      "code": "Q050035",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 330,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Production Transportation",
      "code": "Q050041",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 404,
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "No Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029003",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "531",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "1 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029004",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "2808",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "2 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029005",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "2404",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "3 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029006",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "555",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "4 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029007",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "131",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "5 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029008",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "53",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Aggregate Number of Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029009",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "10078",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
];

var el = ["Q029009","Q017001","Q035001"];

arr = arr.filter(e => e !== el);
console.log(arr)
```

y .

Comment: `arr` is an array *of* arrays, and `el` is an array of strings. By doing `e !== el`, you're comparing an array of objects to an array of strings, which not only won't work, but it's not at all what you want to do. You'll have to filter the inner arrays where `el` does not include the `code` property of the inner array's objects. Or *does* include - your question and code seem to be doing two different things.

Comment: It would be helpful if your snippet was more concise. Secondly - why are you creating an array of objects within an array? If you don't have to I would advise against it, that data structure isn't ideal.

Comment: Your current [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function is not going to address the complex data schema.

Comment: **minimal** example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of arrays, so `.map()` the outer array, and for each inner array return a `.filter()` that makes sure the current object's `.code` is not included in the `el` array.

```
var el = ["Q029009","Q017001","Q035001"];
arr = arr.map(a => a.filter(o => !el.includes(o.code)));
```

Demo:

```js
var arr =[
  [
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ1",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ2",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 19,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ3",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 40,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
      "code": "SEASONAL_LYQ4",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 22,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ1",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ2",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 20,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ3",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 40,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
      "code": "SEASONAL_CYQ4",
      "parent": "SEASONAL_POP",
      "value": 24,
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Total Educated",
      "code": "Q035001",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "9891",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Grade  Less than 9",
      "code": "Q035003",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "514",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Grade 9 to 12",
      "code": "Q035007",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "444",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "High School",
      "code": "Q035011",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "1269",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Some College",
      "code": "Q035012",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "2001",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Associate's",
      "code": "Q035014",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "400",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Bachelor's",
      "code": "Q035015",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "3018",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree -  Master's",
      "code": "Q035016",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "1706",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College - Professional",
      "code": "Q035017",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "315",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "College Degree - Doctorate",
      "code": "Q035018",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "value": "224",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Enrollments (Total Population)",
      "code": "EDU_Enrollments",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Nursery school/Preschool",
          "code": "Q036003",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "330",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Kindergarten/Elementary school",
          "code": "Q036006",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "1158",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "High School",
          "code": "Q036015",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "636",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "College/Graduate /Professional school",
          "code": "Q036018",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "1715",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "Not Enrolled",
          "code": "Q036024",
          "parent": "EDU_Enrollments",
          "value": "10324",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Percents",
      "code": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "parent": "EDU_ATTAINMENT",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "% Grade  Less than 9",
          "code": "XQ035003",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "5.197",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% Grade 9 to 12",
          "code": "XQ035007",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "4.4937",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% High school",
          "code": "XQ035011",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "12.8274",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% Some college",
          "code": "XQ035012",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "20.2347",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Associate",
          "code": "XQ035014",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "4.0479",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Bachelors",
          "code": "XQ035015",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "30.509",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Masters",
          "code": "XQ035016",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "17.2467",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Professional",
          "code": "XQ035017",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "3.1824",
          "children": []
        },
        {
          "name": "% College - Doctorate",
          "code": "XQ035018",
          "parent": "PCT_EDU_ATTAINMENT",
          "value": "2.2612",
          "children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "1 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014010",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2395",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "2 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014011",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2140",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "3 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014012",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "878",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "4 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014013",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "701",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "5 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014014",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "247",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "6 Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014015",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "68",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "7+ Person HHs",
      "code": "Q014016",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "54",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Persons Per HH",
      "code": "Q017001",
      "parent": "HH_by_size",
      "value": "2",
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Occ Managerial Executive",
      "code": "Q050004",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "1748",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Prof Specialty",
      "code": "Q050010",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "2372",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Healthcare Support",
      "code": "Q050024",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "91",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Sales",
      "code": "Q050032",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "1323",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Office Admin",
      "code": "Q050033",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_WHITE_COL",
      "value": "623",
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "Occ Protective",
      "code": "Q050025",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 75,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Food Preparation Serving",
      "code": "Q050028",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 394,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Bldg Maintenance & Cleaning",
      "code": "Q050029",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 183,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Personal Care",
      "code": "Q050030",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 421,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Farming, Fishing & Forestry",
      "code": "Q050034",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 0,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Construction",
      "code": "Q050035",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 330,
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Occ Production Transportation",
      "code": "Q050041",
      "parent": "EMP_16P_BLUE_COL",
      "value": 404,
      "children": []
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "name": "No Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029003",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "531",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "1 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029004",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "2808",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "2 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029005",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "2404",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "3 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029006",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "555",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "4 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029007",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "131",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "5 Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029008",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "53",
      "children": []
    },
    {
      "name": "Aggregate Number of Vehicle",
      "code": "Q029009",
      "parent": "VEHICLES_PER_HH",
      "value": "10078",
      "children": []
    }
  ]
];

var el = ["Q029009","Q017001","Q035001"];

verify("Found codes before removal:", arr, el); // should be `true`

arr = arr.map(a => a.filter(o => !el.includes(o.code)));

verify("Found codes after removal:", arr, el); // should be `false`

console.log(arr)

function verify(msg, arr, el) {
  console.log(msg, arr.some(a => a.some(o => el.includes(o.code))));
}
```